# Terraform - Linux VM issue not being created

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terraform, virtual-machine

I am following along a YouTube video on "Learn Terraform with Azure by Building a Dev Environment – Full Course for Beginners" not sure if i can post links but (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V53AHWun17s) around minute 53, is where i am having the issue. When implementing this section of the code i get this error:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "mtc-vm" {
  name                  = "mtc-vm"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.mtc-rg.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.mtc rg.location
  size                  = "Standard_B1s"
  admin_username        = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.mtc-nic.id]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/mtcazurekey.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {

    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  tags = {
    "environment" = "dev"
  }
}
```

Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine: (Name "mtc-vm" / Resource Group "mtc-resources"): compute.VirtualMachinesclient#CreateOru pdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="Platform ImageNotFound" Message="The platform image 'Canoni cal:UbuntuServer:16.04 LTS:latest' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct. For more details a bout storage profile information, please refer to [https://aka.ms/storageprofile"](https://aka.ms/storageprofile%22) target="imageReference"

with azurerm linux virtual machine.mtc-vm, on main.tf line 97, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual machine" "mtc-vm" : 97: resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "mtc-vm" {

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code nor errors. Use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: *"i get this error"*, what error?  Please provide a [mcve], we will not view the entire video.

Comment: What is your error msg?

Comment: Your code and error do no match. The error clearly writes that you are using Canoni cal:UbuntuServer: **16.04 LTS:latest** , while the TF code is different. Sadly your question is not clear and only causes more confusion.

Comment: @marcin Well this is the code from the terraform resource.

Comment: In your code you have `sku       = "18.04-LTS"`. Error message indictes that you have some other code than what you posted in the question.

Comment: Yeah i changed it back to the correct one but still gave me the same error but i ran the code again after i had to increase the limit on the portal and it works now. Thank you again for your help. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. I will provide an answer to the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments. The issue was caused by using old Ubuntu `16.04 LTS:latest` in the actual TF code. Changing to `18.04-LTS` and modify other settings (not clarified which ones), fixed the issue.